# HP Pavilion dv6000: Jackd problem: (Ubuntu 10.04) I can't start Rakarrak, Mixx, Internet DJ Console and etc

Tags: hp, jack

I have Ubuntu 10.04 (I tried higer, but unity is lagging; yes it's Ubuntu 10.04, it's only theme) and I can't start Rakarrak, Mixx, Internet DJ Console and other programs for mixing songs. It's showing me this (rakarrak):

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/5agx14.jpg].

I tried to start JACK Control server, but it starts and the window goes black and I can't close it.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Ubuntu 10.04 is a LTS and it is still supported, I would recommend switching to a more recent version if your PC can handle it.
However, instead of using plain old Ubuntu, I'd recommend that you check out Ubuntu Studio 14.04 which should be ready to run jack, rakarrak and other music software.  Ubuntu Studio is aimed at artists and has software to fit your needs -- music, photography, video editing, graphic design, etc.
Try Ubuntu Studio 14.04 from a Live disc to see if your computer will handle it.  Keep in mind that running the Live version will be slower than the real thing once it's installed in your computer.  UbuntuStudio runs the Xfce desktop environment which uses fewer resources than Unity and is faster than Unity on older hardware.
[UbuntuStudio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)